# Body speeding off ignoring scrolling ground

Tags: python, box2d

I am currently trying to make a 2D car game with pybox2D
I have gotten to the stage where the ground needs to scroll with the car so it stays on screen.
I have this bit of code doing this currently:

```
ground.body.worldCenter[0] = SW/PPM - car.chassis.worldCenter[0] - (SW//2)/PPM
```

(`SW/PPM -`  and  `- (SW//2)/PPM` are just used to keep it in the middle of the screen and make sure it moves opposite of the car)
`ground` and `car` are instances of special classes I made to connect all parts of the bodies (different sections of ground for concave shapes, wheels, chassis, etc) into objects.
The problem is that the car just speeds off screen still, even though `worldCenter` should always keep track of the object so the car should always be in the center of the screen.
My car movement system is a simple joint motor system.

Does anyone know why this is happening?
More importantly, is this code efficient or is there a better way of tracking a body?

Comment: we can't see your full code, we can't run it, and we can't read in your mind - so we have no idea what can make problem. You have to show all details in question.

Comment: sometimes it can be simpler to create one big `Surface` for all world, draw all on this Surface, and later crop it (using car position) and `blit` only this part in window. Somethink like `x = car_x - (window_width//2)`, `y = car_y - (window_height//2)`, `blit(full_surface, (-x, -y))`  (values `x,y` with minus)

Comment: @furas I can upload my code to something like mystbin. I'm not one to use more than one file for my code though, so you'll have to skip around to find stuff. [code](https://mystb.in/ListingsPtsWord) (code in code.py)